# Worse query plan with a JOIN after ANALYZE

Tags: performance, sqlite

I see that running `ANALYZE` results in significantly poor performance on a particular `JOIN` I'm making between two tables.

Suppose the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE a ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT );
CREATE TABLE b ( a NOT NULL REFERENCES a, value INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(a, b) );

CREATE VIEW ab AS SELECT a.name, b.text, MAX(b.value)
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.a = a.id;
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.name
```

Table a is approximately 10K rows, table b is approximately 48K rows (~5 rows per row in table a).

**Before `ANALYZE`**

Now when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ab;
```

The query plan looks as follows:

```
1|0|0|SCAN TABLE b
1|1|1|SEARCH TABLE a USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

This is a good plan, b is larger and I want it to be in the outer loop, making use of the index in table a. It finishes well within a second.

**After `ANALYZE`**

When I execute the same query again, the query plan results in two table scans:

```
1|0|1|SCAN TABLE a
1|1|0|SCAN TABLE b
```

This is far for optimal. For some reason the query planner thinks that an outer loop of 10K rows and an inner loop of 48K rows is a better fit. This takes about 1.5 minute to complete.

Should I adapt the index in table b to make it work after `ANALYZE`? Anything else to change to the indexing/schema?

I just try to understand the problem here. I worked around it using a `CROSS JOIN`, but that feels dirty and I don't really understand why the planner would go with a plan that is orders of magnitude slower than the un-analyzed plan. It seems to be related to `GROUP BY`, since the query planner puts table b in the outer loop without it (but that renders the query useless for what I want).

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally found the answer by adjusting the `GROUP BY` clause in the view definition. Instead of joining on `a.id`, I group on `b.a` instead, although they have the same values.

```
CREATE VIEW ab AS SELECT a.name, b.text, MAX(b.value)
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.a = a.id;
GROUP BY b.a            --   <== changed this from a.id to b.a
ORDER BY a.name
```

I'm still not entirely sure what the difference is, since it groups the same data.